# Query branches in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online)

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

We have recently moved our source code from on-premise to Visual Studio Team Services, and I am having some issues trying to migrate some of the code.
I have created a test branch, but QueryRootBranchObjects in the below code is not returning anything.

Anything I am missing?

```
        var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(Configuration.ServiceUri));
        tfs.EnsureAuthenticated(); 
        var versionControl = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

        var mybranches = versionControl.QueryRootBranchObjects(RecursionType.Full);
        foreach (var br in mybranches) //nothing here
        {
            Console.WriteLine(br);
        }
```

Comment: Which version control system are you using for the project? TFVC or Git?

Comment: Does the test branch have parent? "QueryRootBranchObjects" only return the branches have no parent.

Comment: OK, it is working now. The problem was that although I had branched the folder I hadn't made it into a branch. Selecting "Convert to Branch" seems to have fixed it thanks